# Changing images on hover with CSS

Tags: css, image

I can't seem to figure this out.
I want to have a system whereby an image will change to another image upon hover over.

In my html I have:

```
<div class="linkyimage">
<img src="image/red.png" alt="red" />
    <p class="hovvery"<img src="image/black.png"></p>
</div>
```

And then in my css:

```
.linkyimage{
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    width:250px:    
}   

.hovvery{
    position: absolute;
    height: 250px;
    width:250px:
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.linkyimage:hover .hovvery {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Yet nothing seems to happen for me. Where am I going wrong?

edit:

Still can't seem to get any effect.....

```
.linkyimage{
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    width:250px; 
}   

.hovvery{
    position: absolute;
    height: 250px;
    width:250px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
    }

.linkyimage:hover .hovvery{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
    }
```

and html:

```
<div id="content">

    <div class="linkyimage">
    <img src="image/red.png" alt="red" />
    <p class="hovvery"<img src="image/black.png" /></p>
    </div>

    <img src="image/yellow.png">
    <img src="image/lblue.png">
    <img src="image/green.png">
    <img src="image/brown.png">

    <div class"linkyimage">
    <img src="image/dblue.png" alt"blue" />
    <p class="hovvery"<img src="image/black.png" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm going for sort of a gallery of images, which on mouse over change to the black image- in the futuer I will make it so a description of the image appears over it but for now trying to get the basics going!

Comment: Your `p` elements didn't close.

Comment: syntax errors fixed now. Still doesn't seem to work out, hmm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/NxesW/2/)**</kbd>

You didn't close `p` in this line:

```
<p class="hovvery"<img src="image/black.png"></p>
```

Correct code:

```
<div class="linkyimage">
    <img src="image/red.png" alt="red" />
    <p class="hovvery"><img src="image/black.png" /></p>
</div>
```

Also you have syntax error in your CSS here:

```
width:250px: /* it must be semicolon ; at the end */
```

Change it to this:

```
width: 250px;
```

Comment: woops. Ta. Fixed that but the problem remains. The fiddle works there (albeit doing something different to what I intended) but nought happens on my site. Hmm....

Comment: Your CSS has invalid syntax, in the `width:250px:`. I've added information in my answer.

Comment: I need glasses it seems :(
Oh well. Still doesn't seem to do anything for me. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Based on your CSS and HTML, it works (as in jsFiddle demo). But if it didn't work for you, maybe you need to add the complete code here to debug...

Comment: I can get it working like  the fiddle demo, making another image appear next to the first image. Can't seem to get it working with the image changing to another image.

Comment: Think I figured it out. Key is to have the other one be positioned relative whilst the main one is positioned absolute.